# How to Remove -14 from WordPress URL (Permalink)

Tags: permalinks, urls

Why does it have a number on my permalink
[image: Before saving]

But after I hit save it automatically adds a number
[image: After saving]

Answer (score 2):

WordPress makes sure that the URLs are unique. It means that when you publish multiple posts with the same slug (post_name), then WP will try to make them unique by adding numbers at the end of slug.

So most probably this is the case. You have to check if there are other posts with the same slug (they may be located in trash).

After you find them, you'll have to delete them permanently and then you'll be able to publish your post without additional number at the end.